# To find the next from a match of data-frame splits

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A data frame as below and a list of names.

```
['Amelia','Elijah','Amelia']
```

[image]

I want to find out, who's the next, when a portion of the data frame matches the given names (the list of names is a fixed sequence). (it's 1990-09-01 00:00:00 James)

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

to_find_list = ['Amelia','Elijah','Amelia']

short_frame = 3

csvfile = StringIO(
"""Date Staff
1990-05-01 00:00:00 Mason
1990-06-01 00:00:00 Amelia
1990-07-01 00:00:00 Elijah
1990-08-01 00:00:00 Amelia
1990-09-01 00:00:00 James
1990-10-01 00:00:00 Benjamin
1990-11-01 00:00:00 Isabella
1990-12-01 00:00:00 Lucas
1991-01-01 00:00:00 Mason""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

# split the df into small frames with overlaps
list_of_dfs = [df.loc[i:i + short_frame-1,:].reset_index(drop=True) for i in range(0, len(df), short_frame - 2) if i < len(df) - 2]          

for son_df in list_of_dfs:

    first_cell = son_df.iloc[0]['Date']
    last_cell = son_df.iloc[-1]['Date']

    if son_df['Staff'].to_list() == to_find_list:
        found_date = son_df['Date'].iloc[-1]                # 1990-08-01 00:00:00 
        who = df['Staff'].loc[df['Date'] == found_date]     # Amelia
```

I've tried to use shift() to print our the next Date and Staff next to "Amelia" but not successful.

What's the best way to achieve it?

Comment: these values `['Amelia','Elijah','Amelia']` are always occur together..I mean one after another in the given sequence?

Comment: @Anurag Dabas, yes, it's a fixed sequence.

Comment: date and staff are 2 different columns or 1 column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do

```
m = pd.concat([df['Staff'].shift(x)==y for x, y  in zip(range(3),['Amelia','Elijah','Amelia'])]).all(level=0)
idx = m.index[m]+1
idx
Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')
df.loc[idx]
                      Date  Staff
4      1990-09-01 00:00:00  James
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try `extract()` and get the index where values occurs:

```
idx=df['Staff'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(to_find_list)})', expand=False).dropna().index
```

Finally pass that index:

```
out=df.loc[[x+3 for x in idx if x <=len(df)]]
             #^
        #if you add 1 then you will get the 1st member of next staff
```

output of `out`:

```
    Date                    Staff
4   1990-09-01 00:00:00     James
5   1990-10-01 00:00:00     Benjamin
6   1990-11-01 00:00:00     Isabella
```

**OR**

```
out=df.loc[[x+3 for x in idx if x <=len(df)],'Staff']
             #^
        #if you add 1 then you will get the 1st member of next staff
```

output of `out`:

```
4       James
5    Benjamin
6    Isabella
```

**Performance:**

[image]

Comment: thank you! Can I have your understanding to choose another one, which seems simpler for the answer?

Comment: @MarkK It's upto you...if you found the other one simple then choose that one but for performance wise `extract()` will be fast...added ss of performance via `%%timeit` **:)**

Answer (score 1):

You could create new columns using the pd.DataFrame shift() function. Then a list comprehension to match the to_find_list vs the columns converted to a list.

```
>>> df['Staff_prev'] = df['Staff'].shift(1)
>>> df['Staff_prev2'] = df['Staff'].shift(2)
>>> df['Staff_prev3'] = df['Staff'].shift(3)
>>> df['my_row'] = [ to_find_list == [ row['Staff_prev'], row['Staff_prev2'], row['Staff_prev3'] ] for index, row in df.iterrows()  ]
>>> df.head()
                  Date   Staff Staff_prev Staff_prev2 Staff_prev3  my_row
0  1990-05-01 00:00:00   Mason        NaN         NaN         NaN   False
1  1990-06-01 00:00:00  Amelia      Mason         NaN         NaN   False
2  1990-07-01 00:00:00  Elijah     Amelia       Mason         NaN   False
3  1990-08-01 00:00:00  Amelia     Elijah      Amelia       Mason   False
4  1990-09-01 00:00:00   James     Amelia      Elijah      Amelia    True

>>> df.loc[df['my_row'] == True, 'Date']
1990-09-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: This doesn't scale to handle an arbitrarily long or short list of names, but it's gosh darn easy to read and understand. Upvote.